# passing data from one fragment to another fragment without changing fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have one activity `HomeActivity` and I have `HomePageFragment` which have some categories with icon and title of data, when I click on any category I'm sending the clicked item Title name with bundle and opening `MultipleFragment` and I'm getting clicked title name from the previous fragment, on this multiple fragments I have viewpager inside it.. 
1) `PostFragment`, 
2) `TextFragment`
now here's my main question that I want to send clicked item title name to `PostFragment` and `TextFragment`, 
**HomeFragment**

```
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    MultiplePost multiplePost = new MultiplePost();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Categories categoriesClicked = categoriesList.get(position);
    args.putString(Title, categoriesClicked.getTitle());
    args.putString(ImageUrl, categoriesClicked.getIcon());
    multiplePost.setArguments(args);
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_frame,multiplePost)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
}
```

**MultiplePost**

```
public class MultiplePost extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter;
    private View view;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    public static String title ;


    public MultiplePost() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_multiple_post, container, false);

        title = getArguments().getString("title");
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);
        viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        viewPageAdapter.AddFragment(new PostFragment(), "");
        viewPageAdapter.AddFragment(new TextFragment(), "");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.photo);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.file);

        PostFragment post = new PostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        post.setArguments(args);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               .replace(R.id.main_frame, post)
               .commit();// and this's changing whole fragment with PostFragment and 
//so i can't see my viewpager on MultiplePost
        return view;
    }

}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> listFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return listFragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listTitle.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return listTitle.get(position);
    }

    public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        listFragment.add(fragment);
        listTitle.add(title);
    }

}
```

How to send title onto PostFragment and TextFragment into viewpager

Comment: sorry for indentation it's my first question here

Comment: So what's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: i'm getting title which is passing from HomeFragment, but here on MultiplePost Fragment i have viewpager 1) PostFragment, 2) TextFragment, so how to send data of title to my both viewpager fragment

Comment: in AddFragment() can't you put in argument of fragment you're passing

Comment: if i'm sending data from MultiplePost fragment like                       PostFragment post = new PostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        post.setArguments(args);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                .add(R.id.main_frame, post)
                .commit();               then it'll change my whole Fragment from Multiplefragment which i don't want

Comment: @TheGoldy that's for viewpager title like post and text, and i want to send clicked title data which i'm getting from MultiplePost,